# Can grep delete context, but not a full line?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am removing keys from a config file by the following command:

```
cat showrunningconfig.txt | grep -v '[ \t\r\n\v\f]*[A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]'
```

This removes the whole line.
But I want to remove only the relevant patterns.
grep has the -o option, which shows only the relevant pattern and not the whole line.
But the -o option is not working in combination with -v

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Better use `sed` for that.

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know for better understanding.

Comment: Try `LC_ALL=C sed -i 's/[[:space:]]*[A-Fa-f0-9]\{8\}//g' showrunningconfig.txt`

Comment: You can also use `[[:xdigit:]]` instead of `[A-Fa-f0-9]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `sed` when you have a partial pattern to remove from a string.

```
sed -i 's/[[:space:]]*[[:xdigit:]]\{8\}//g' showrunningconfig.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/wd0PBS)

```
s="Text A1f4E3D4 and more text"
sed 's/[[:space:]]*[[:xdigit:]]\{8\}//g' <<< "$s"
# => Text and more text
```

**Details**

- `-i` - in-place replacement (GNU `sed` option)
- `s/[[:space:]]*[[:xdigit:]]\{8\}//g`:

  - `s` - substitute command
  - `[[:space:]]*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `[[:xdigit:]]\{8\}` - eight `A-F`, `a-f` and `0-9` chars.